# Reputation in Data Explorer is different from Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, reputation

My actual reputation, which I can see on my profile, is 986.

However, when I run a query on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), it says my reputation is only 769.

Why this difference in reputation? Is the database not the same as the actual one used by the site? Is it a backup of the actual database used?

Answer (score 9):

From [the FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq):

> #### How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?
>
> The data is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was May 11 at 5:44.

On May 11th, when Data Explorer was last updated, your reputation was 769. It'll be more come next Monday.